# horizontal and vertical pinned on a html table

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I'm trying to get a table with both sides pinned.
I've tried with Javascript and CSS and I did get the top side pinned and the left side pinned individually but not both at the same time.
Here is some working code for fixed vertical side:

```
.table-pinned tr > th:first-child {
    width: 240px;
    height: 55px;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background: #eee;
}

.table-pinned tr td:nth-child(2),
.table-pinned tr th:nth-child(2) {
    padding-left: 241px;
    width: 480px;
}
```

here is the code I have now: https://jsfiddle.net/5L6cyut8/

Comment: Define pinned, please?

Comment: with pinned I ment that it stays in view when scrolling like the left side in the example

Comment: You want to add a floating row?

Comment: for both horizontal as vertical

Comment: Review my answer, let me know if I'm close.